# Include a partial in Mustache JS

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have an html template in a `var template` and an object in `var obj`.
I call my template in **Javascript** like this.

```
var html = Mustache.render(template, obj, {
  templateRef: "path/template"
});
```

If I console.log `html`, the original template display perfectly, but the partial *(templateRef)* section is not rendered at all.
In my template, I have a reference to the partial like this:

```
{{> templateRef}}
```

I tried to put the partial on the same level *(Remove path)*, include extension *(.mustache)*, etc. But nothing seems to work.
Anyone have an idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't appear that Mustache.js supports [specifying a partial by its path](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#partials):

> The object should be keyed by the name of the partial, and **its value should be the partial text**.

You'll have to retrieve the template's text and provide that to `Mustache.render()` (e.g., with jQuery):

```
$.get('path/template.mustache', function (partialTemplate) {

  var html = Mustache.render(template, obj, {
    templateRef: partialTemplate
  });

  // ...

}, 'text');
```

Comment: Thank you, when I retrieve the template's text everything work great!

Answer (score 6):

Editing answer to relate to MustacheJS (not handlebars - my mistake). You should be able to pass the Partial template into the main template, like so:

```
var data = {
    firstName: "Christophe",
    lastName: "Coenraets",
    address: "1 Main street",
    city: "Boston",
    state: "MA",
    zip: "02106"
};

var template = "<h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>{{>address}}";
var partials = {address: "<p>{{address}}</p>{{city}}, {{state}} {{zip}}"};
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data, partials);
$('#sampleArea').html(html);
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LUvpM/
Reference: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/

Comment: Oh the irony of handlebar mustaches.

Comment: Updated my answer for Mustache - sorry and thanks for the catch! I had Handlebars on the brain I guess :)

Comment: I like your example thank you, but what if both template and partial are external?

Comment: If you're storing templates inside something like `<script id="template-name">` tags, you can use jquery to collect the contents using `$('#template-name').html()`.

If they are stored in a file, consider precompiling your templates and refer to them all by including a compiled JS file. Doing some quick searches, the best I found was hogan.js for Mustache (consider switching to Handlebars for this functionality. http://askmike.org/2013/09/hoganizer-precompile-mustache-templates-for-the-frontend/